# Save state of DIV element to LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, checkbox, local-storage

I would like hide/show some div's elements, depends on the checkboxes. 
I have checkboxes, state was saved to localStorage but my DIV element after refresh are unsaved (load with default state). jQuery(-mobile).
Many thanks for your help.

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical" data-mini="true">
    <legend>Some text.</legend>
    <div id="checkbox1">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-theme="a" name="ligne1" data-iconpos="right" checked="checked" />Ligne 1</label>
    </div>
    <div id="checkbox2">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-theme="a" name="ligne2" data-iconpos="right" checked="checked" />Ligne 2</label>
    </div>
    <div id="checkbox3">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-theme="a" name="ligne3" data-iconpos="right" checked="checked" />Ligne 3</label>
    </div>
    <fieldset>

$(document).ready(function () {
function getCurrentValue(checkMe) {
    return checkMe.is(':checkbox') ? checkMe.prop('checked') : checkMe.val();
}

function checkvalues() {
    var original = true;
    $(':input').each(function () {
        if (getCurrentValue($(this)) !== $(this).data('originalvalue')) {
            original = false;
        }
    });

    return original;
}

if (localStorage) {

    $(':input').each(function () {

        $(this).data('originalvalue', getCurrentValue($(this)));
    });

    $('#checkbox1').on('change', ':input', function () {
        if (checkvalues()) {
            $('#ligne1').show();
        } else {
            $('#ligne1').hide();
        }
    });

    $('#checkbox2').on('change', ':input', function () {
        if (checkvalues()) {
            $('#ligne2').show();
        } else {
            $('#ligne2').hide();
        }
    });

    $('#checkbox3').on('change', ':input', function () {
        if (checkvalues()) {
            $('#ligne3').show();
        } else {
            $('#ligne3').hide();
        }
    });

}});
```

Live example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jyHqt/).

Comment: Looking through your code I can't see anywhere that the state is saved to localStorage or retrieved from it.

Comment: Now I added JavaScript ;-) but it was in example.

Comment: don't do this: `if (localStorage)...` because if it doesn't exist - you'll get an error. Instead do this: `if (typeof localStorage !== 'undefined')`...` or: `if (window.localStorage)...`

Comment: There is still no read/write to/from `localStorage` in your code...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the set and get from localStorage in your code.

To set data you need something like this:

```
// First we setup the data in key/value pairs
var dataContainer = { 'check1':'checked', 'check2':'notchecked'}
// Then save it to localStorage
localStorage.setItem('storedData', JSON.stringify(dataContainer));
```

And to get data from localStorage:

```
var dataRetrieved = localStorage.getItem('storedData');
console.log('Local Storage data:', JSON.parse(dataRetrieved))
```

More info on localStorage [MDN Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/DOM/Almacenamiento)